# Order query results in a many-to-many join table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, many-to-many, sql-order-by, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm coding a website in .NET Core 3.1 using Razor Pages and Entity Framework Core. I have the following two tables, `Comics` and `ApplicationUser` (custom fields added to `IdentityUser`). I have implemented the code to enable a user to add/remove any comic to his/her favourites by way of a Many-to-Many join table `UserComic`. All this code works fine.

```
public class Comic
{
    public Comic()
    {
        UserComics = new List<UserComic>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...

    public List<UserComic> UserComics { get; set; }
}


public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        UserComics = new List<UserComic>();
    }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    ...

    public List<UserComic> UserComics { get; set; }
}
```

Many-to-many join table

```
public class UserComic
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public int ComicId { get; set; }
    public Comic Comic { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm struggling on, is that I want the User to be able to view all his favourited comics ordered by the join table `DateAdded` field.

I have implemented the following query on the Users table:

```
var user = await _context.Users
                         .Include(c => c.UserComics)
                         .ThenInclude(c => c.Comic)
                         .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == UserId);

UserFavs = user.UserComics.OrderByDescending(c => c.DateAdded).ToList();
```

Although this works, it's far from perfect as I cannot find a way to order by `DateAdded` in the join table `UserComic` in the initial query. Also if I want to implement paging at a later date if a user has favourited a large number of comics, ALL data has been returned from the database already, so it's not efficient by any means.

I also implemented the following query on the `Comics` table:

```
var comics = await _context.Comics
                           .Include(c => c.UserComics)
                           .ThenInclude(u => u.User)
                           .Where(c => c.UserComcis.Any(u => u.UserId == UserId))
                           .ToListAsync();
```

This seems a step in the right direction, but again I cannot order by the join table `DateAdded` field, but I'm capable of implementing paging on the results if needed.

Comment: Put the order by before the where.

Comment: If you want to implement paging later, I suggest separate loading User table data from the UserComics data for maintainability. When you search by server side pagination, just search by _context.UserComic from the UserId foreign key and you can paginate easily.

Comment: Start the query at `UserComics`. Then you can order by `DateAdded` and `Include` `User` and `Comic`.

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold From your advice and Shafiq Hussain, added `DbSet` for `UserComics` and tweaked code accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var comics = await _context.UserComics
                            .Where(u => u.UserId == UserId)
                           .Include(c => c.Comics)
                           .OrderByDescending(a => a.DateEnded)
                           .Select(a => a.Comics).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Great! After adding a DbSet for UserComics and adding migration, the above code does exactly what I needed. Thank you Shafiq

Comment: Thank you and welcome @Mike, also don't forget to give me point :)